# What measure of test reliability is appropriate if the final test output is not the sum of item scores?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics

I would like to compute a measure of reliability in the sense of Cronbach's alpha, McDonalds omega or glb. However it seems to me that all these measures assume that the final test score equates to the sum of item scores.

In my case I have a likelihood for each item (e.g. the probability of the observed answer time given the participant belongs to group A). The different likelihoods are combined to the final probabilistic output using Bayes formula.

Are there any appropriate measures for assessing test reliability in such cases?

Comment: It seems that you are doing some analysis similar to IRT, so this could be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/reliability-in-irt-style/132771

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Tim . This is indeed interesting. IRT, however, seems to model only the probability of a correct response. I guess I would need to follow the analysis in IRT, but use different response models (e.g. a model for the answer time given latent student ability) instead.