# Reliablity and validity new questionnaire

Tags: hypothesis-testing, reliability, validity

A questionnaire with three subtopics concerning; well being, competence and empathy is adjusted and translated by us.

We would like to know whether our new, shorter version of this questionnaire is valid and reliable. Therefore we would like to compare scores on our three sub topics with the scores on the same sub topics from three other questionnaires, already  adjusted by other researchers (also concerning well being, competence and empathy). All items are rated on a Likert scale (1 not at all, 5 very much). The new questionnaire with questions about well being, competence and empathy plus the items from the already adjusted questionnaires concerning well being competence and empathy, are all rated on the same day by the same person (n=40).

How can we test the reliability and validity of our new test by comparing the scores of sub topics of our test, with the scores of sub topics from other adjusted questionnaires concerning the same three subtopics of our new questionnaire? And besides this way of testing, are there other tests we can run to test validity and reliability, besides Cronbachs Alpha?

Also, we predict that the sum of the sub topics in our new questionnaire will have a direct influence on the scores of a questionnaire concerning quality of life (Likert scale). How can we test this relation. And how can we test for each of the sub topics how they relate to quality of life? I guess factor analyses is out of the question with only 40 people in our study.

Comment: You may think of using IRT, e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/reliability-in-irt-style

Comment: Thanks! And how would you examine the relationship between scores on the new test and scores on quality of life?