# Calculation of reliability of scale scores in an IRT- model

Tags: reliability, item-response-theory, mirt

While trying to compute the reliability of scale scores obtained from IRT models (bifactor models and unidimensional models) I was wondering why there are so many published papers who report omega categorical/ omega hierarchical or even cronbachs alpha, even though those are reliability estimates conducted unter a CTT approach?

Which reliability coefficient is recommended for scale scores and how do I compute it in RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

They're reported because people expect them and reviewers ask for them. It's a  single summary indicator of how well the scale hangs together - it's not ideal, but it's not (IMHO) useless. If the reliability estimate is 0.5 or 0.9, that tells you something.

For the second part of your question, does this answer help: [Reliability in IRT Style](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/reliability-in-irt-style)