# How do I calculate different reliabilty levels of theta when standard error of theta is known? (IRT-model)

Tags: reliability, item-response-theory, mirt

I've recently seen a plot where the level of reliability is given for different SE values of theta estimates: [image: plot with reliability levels]

I have also plotted the standard errors of theta as a function of theta but now I am wondering how to calculate at which SE value the different reliability levels are? How is the formula for reliability in IRT models or which coefficient could have been used here?

Comment: In your last question @Jeremy Miles linked to a realy helpful [stats.stackexchange posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/reliability-in-irt-style). The `R` code therein answers your present question. Note that the object `e` in the code is the standard error.

Comment: also, you have several open questions that are thoughtfully answered. Might want to consider accepting some of the answers as accepted.