# Computing IRT score reliability across a range of ability in mirt

Tags: reliability, item-response-theory, scale-construction, mirt

I am using `mirt` and would like to get reliability estimates across a range of ability for a 1-factor scale. Essentially, I would like to extract the data used to make the plot produced by `plot(mod, type = 'rxx')` (where `mod` is a unidimensional `mirt` model).

By looking at [this very helpful thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/reliability-in-irt-style/132771#132771=) I believe I have what I need (see below). However I'm still posting here 1) to verify that I'm computing reliability in a sensible way, and 2) because I didn't find a question like this already answered, so others may find this useful.

Here's the code I'm using (note: `qplot` is from the `ggplot2` package)

```
theta <- seq(-2,4,.001)
ti <- testinfo(mod,theta)
rxx <- ti / (1 + ti)
qplot(Theta,rxx)
```

This yields the following plot:

[image: home-made reliability plot]

Which looks pretty similar to what I get from `plot(mod, type = "rxx")`

[image: mirt-made reliability plot]

Am I on the right track here? All input appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks correct for me, assuming that VAR(theta) = 1 by construction. Also, `mirt` is open-source, so you're welcome to verify the code computations directly.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @philchalmers! I looked at the code for`mirt`'s `plot` and had some trouble following it (of course it is written to account for more complex cases than what I have here). The source for `marginal_rxx` was quite helpful.