# How to interpret the Rasch reliability?

Tags: logistic, reliability, item-response-theory, social-science, rasch

I am tasked to model a set of questionnaires in order to investigate about the food insecurity in the region where my project takes place. Using the Rasch model, I was able to conduct the protocol provided by the FAO organisation and the values respect the ranges of validity. However, I will be charged of communicating my results with my team, and I am a bit confused on how to explain to them in a simple way the Rasch reliabilty.

Would appreciate the help.

You can check here for more details about the FIES protocol :
https://www.fao.org/3/ca9318en/ca9318en.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasch model is one of several models in the family of Item Response Theory psychometric models. You can find how reliability is defined for those models in the [Reliability in IRT Style](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132738/reliability-in-irt-style/132771#132771) thread:

> In Classical Test Theory observed test scores $X$ could be defined as:
>
> $$X = T + E$$
>
> where $T$ are the true scores and $E$ is an error of measurement. This
> means that their variance is:
>
> $$\sigma^2_X = \sigma^2_T + \sigma^2_E$$
>
> In this case, [reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28psychometrics%29) could be defined as:
>
> $$ \rho_{xx'} = \frac{\sigma^2_T}{\sigma^2_X} = \frac{\sigma^2_X -
>  \sigma^2_E}{\sigma^2_X} = 1 - \frac{ \sigma^2_E }{ \sigma^2_X } $$
>
> In classical test theory $\sigma^2_E$ error variance and $\sigma^2_X$
> observed score variance.

The same applies to the Rasch model as discussed [here](https://rasch.org/rmt/rmt63i.htm) or in the paper by [Patricia Martinkova (2007)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267987830_Reliability_in_the_Rasch_model).

The explanation is pretty simple: *we can decompose the observed scores $X$ into the true (unobservable) scores $T$ and error of measurement $E$, $X = T + E$, in such a case the reliability can be defined as the ratio of the variance of the true scores divided by the variance of the observed data $\sigma^2_T / \sigma^2_X$, that tells us how much variability of the data is explained by the true scores. A perfectly reliable test would explain everything and give reliability of 1, while a completely unreliable would explain nothing and give reliability of 0.* This is consistent with the general definition of [reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28psychometrics%29)

> "It is the characteristic of a set of test scores that relates to the amount of random error from the measurement process that might be embedded in the scores. [...]"

Comment: Thank you so much